# WPF image cropping

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

I'm loading layers of images to make a single image.  I'm currently stacking them all onto a canvas.  I've got it set up so the user can specify the final dimensions of the single image, but even when I change the size of the canvas the images retain their original sizes.

I tried to modify the image size as I was loading them in, but the sizes were NaN and the Actual Sizes were 0 so I couldn't change them there.

I'm starting to think that canvas might not be the way to go.  Any suggestions to how I could clip images to fit a specific size?

```
        canvas1.Children.Clear();
        int totalImages = Window1.GetNumberOfImages();
        if (drawBackground)
            canvas1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b));
        else
            canvas1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < totalImages; i++)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = Window1.GetNextImage(i);

            canvas1.Children.Add(image);                
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current sizes of the canvas, you must first call `Measure` and `Arrange`. This will avoid the NaNs and 0s.

Use `RenderTransform` to change the size of the image that the Canvas displays.

I have never tried to crop an image, so I don't know how to do that, but I see that there is a CroppedBitmap object. I guess you tried that already?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, didn't even know about it!  I'll give that a try once I can get back to my own computer.

Comment: I changed the inside of the for loop to the following and it works now.

Image image = new Image();

BitmapSource tempSource = Window1.GetNextImage(i);

CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(tempSource,

    new Int32Rect(0, 0, 

    Math.Min((int)Window1.totalWinWidth, tempSource.PixelWidth), 

    Math.Min((int)Window1.totalWinHeight, tempSource.PixelHeight)));


image.Source = cb;

canvas1.Children.Add(image);

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who's doing the same thing here's the code that I got working.  Thanks Jeffrey!

```
            Image image = new Image();
            BitmapSource tempSource = Window1.GetNextImage(i);
            CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(tempSource,
                        new Int32Rect(0, 0, 
                            Math.Min((int)Window1.totalWinWidth, tempSource.PixelWidth), 
                            Math.Min((int)Window1.totalWinHeight, tempSource.PixelHeight)));
            image.Source = cb;

            canvas1.Children.Add(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you should be modifying the size of the image sources, not just the canvas.  Canvas is just a container, it doesn't have the capability to modify its children.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm trying to do.  However when I load them in the sizes were set to NaN and 0.

Comment: What's the type of the object being returned from Window1.GetNextImage(i)?  That's the one with NaN and 0?

Comment: It's a BitmapSource.  I'm sure that it has the right information for the size, but when I load it into the Image the Image doesn't have the correct sizes.